# custom tags in web.config

Tags: c#, web-config, configuration-files, custom-tags

I have created custom tags in my web.config file using configuration file which looks like this :

```
<ParentTag>
    <ChildTag>
        <add param1="some value" param2="some value" param3="some value />
        <add param1="some other value" param2="some other value" param3="some other value">
    </ChildTag>
<ParentTag>
```

I was wondering if it's possible to create something like this :

```
<ParentTag>
    <ChildTag_1>
        <add param1="some value" param2="some value" param3="some value" />
        <add param1="some other value" param2="some other value" param3="some other value">
    </ChildTag_1>

    <ChildTag_2>
        <add param1="some value" param2="some value" param3="some value" />
        <add param1="some other value" param2="some other value" param3="some other value">
    </ChildTag_2>
<ParentTag>
```

what changes should I make to the configuration file in order to achieve this? Or is this not achievable at all? Can somebody explain please

I followed this link to create custom tags:

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-add-custom-configuration-settings-for-an-aspnet-application--net-9590

Comment: Is there any particular reason you aren't just using the [appSettings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa903313(v=vs.71).aspx) section?

Comment: Well, it looks like you want to create collection of collections in your config section. You can do this. But it will look pretty odd.

Comment: @MaKCbIMKo It may look odd, but I can attest that such a structure has its usefulness. It's all going to be in how you name things as to just how odd it will look.

Comment: @Hill You don't get Intellisense support on `appSettings`.

Comment: That and you cannot use `appSettings` with custom types AFAIK

Answer (score 0):

Use ConfigurationElementCollection, as it is stated in your sample, by the feed items.

```
public class FeedElementCollection : ConfigurationElementCollection
```